# Not the same output when using Messagepack encoding on Golang and Rust

Tags: go, serialization, rust, deserialization, msgpack

I am trying to make communicate a Go server with a Rust client (and vice-versa), and to do so, I want to serialize (or Marshal as you would say in Go) a struct in order to send it.
Here are my codes :

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack/v5"
)

func ExampleMarshal() {
    type Human struct {
        Age byte
    }
    var x = Human{Age: 42}
    b, err := msgpack.Marshal(x)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("b:", b)
    
}

func main () {
    ExampleMarshal()
} // took from https://github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack
```

```rust
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate rmp_serde as rmps;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use rmps::{Deserializer, Serializer};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Human {
    age: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    let val = Human {
        age: 42,
    };

    val.serialize(&mut Serializer::new(&mut buf)).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", buf);
} // took from https://docs.rs/rmp-serde/latest/rmp_serde/
```

The problem is that with the exact same values, I don't get the same serialized value

- Go -> b: [129 163 65 103 101 204 42]
- Rust -> [145, 42]

Can someone explain me why I don't get the exact same values ?
My goal is to have the Go Output the same as the Rust one

Comment: Based on the Rust output it does not seem that it serialized the same structure since there are only 2 bytes.

Comment: Go has serialized the object as a map, and has explicitly named the "Age" field. Rust has serialized it as an array with a single element. See [the spec](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md)

Comment: It looks like you need to use `Serializer::new_named` to get the Go-like behaviour of serializing structs as maps, rather than as arrays.

Comment: @canton7 what doc are you referring to? In the latest I can find it seems to be [`Serializer::new(W).with_struct_map()`](https://docs.rs/rmp-serde/latest/rmp_serde/encode/struct.Serializer.html#method.with_struct_map).

Comment: @edoode since you're building the thing, [you can also configure the Go side to encode structs as arrays](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack/v5#Encoder.UseArrayEncodedStructs), less self-descriptive but more compact, either way you'll have to take care to document your pick.

Comment: @Masklinn Well spotted, thanks. I was looking at an old version of the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full answer for my own question.

The rust part was good, it was only the Go one that had a "problem", if we can call this a problem.

After digging the internet, I have found that I should use "Compact Encoding" in order to have the desired result.

- https://github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack/blob/v4.0.4/encode.go#L105

The solution was to import the v4.0.4 version of msgpack in golang, and set to true, the UseCompactEncoding flag.

To conclude this thread, here are the codes that returns the exact same output using msgpack :

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use rmp_serde::{Deserializer, Serializer};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct Human {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let x = Human { name: "nice".to_string(), age: 69 };
    let buf = rmp_serde::to_vec(&x).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", buf);
}
```

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/vmihailenco/msgpack"
)

func main() {
    type Human struct {
        Name string
        Age  uint64
    }
    
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    enc := msgpack.NewEncoder(&buf).StructAsArray(true).UseCompactEncoding(true)
    err := enc.Encode(&Human{Name: "nice", Age: 69})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(buf.Bytes())
}
```

Golang output : [146 69 164 110 105 99 101]

Rust output: [146, 69, 164, 110, 105, 99, 101]